# Sort array with recursive function call?

Tags: php, sorting, arrays, recursion

I need the following array in alphabetical order (at all levels), but `asort` doesn't seem to work because I have a recursive call in my function (or so I think); it only partially sorts my array, so I'll have chunks of it that are alphabetized, but they'll be out of order.

Help!

Ex. Directory Listing:

```
apartments.html
js/
  application.js
  jquery.js
  something.js
css/
  reset.css
  master.css
preview.html
ab_restaurant_at_the_end_of_the_universe.jpg
```

Desired output:

```
array() { 
  [0] => string() "ab_restaurant_at_the_end_of_the_universe.jpg"
  [1] => string() "apartments.html"
  ["css"] => array() {
    [0] => string() "master.css"
    [1] => string() "reset.css"
  }
  ["js"] => array() {
    [0] => string() "application.js"
    [1] => string() "jquery.js"
    [2] => string() "something.js"
  }
  [2] => string() "preview.html"
}
```

---

```
function directory_list($directory) {
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($directory)) {
      if ($curr_dir = opendir($directory)) {
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($curr_dir))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "apartment" && $file != "blog") {
        if (is_dir($directory. "/" . $file)) {
          $files[$file] = directory_list($directory. "/" . $file);
        } else {
         $files[] = $file;
        }
       }
      }
      closedir($curr_dir);
     }
    }
    //asort($files); <-- doesn't work; sorts, but interrupts itself because of self-referencing call above (I think)
    return $files;
  }
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sample directory listing and the expected output?

Comment: -1 for not providing requested information.

Comment: Errr... Your desired output isn't in alphabetical order? Entry 0 and 1 should be switched (ab < ap).

Comment: @Wim Vandersmissen - Haha! You are too right; corrected. I feel like I spend more time typing the question than actually working on fixing it. Ah, c'est la vie... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `$files[] = $file;` to `$files[$file] = $file;`, then you can use ksort() where you tried to use asort()